# Cannot centered of a row with tabularx and ding in Pifont package

Tags: tables, tabularx

I type following program.

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\cmark}{{\Large\bfseries\color{green!50!black}\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{{\Large\bfseries\color{red!50!black}\ding{55}}}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cCCCC}
                                     & {\scriptsize EAP-MD5} & {\scriptsize PEAP} & {\scriptsize EAP-TTLS} & {\scriptsize EAP-TLS} \\
            \hline
            ServerEC\footnotemark[1] & \xmark                & \cmark             & \cmark                 & \cmark                \\
            \hline
            ClientEC\footnotemark[1] & \xmark                & \xmark             & \xmark                 & \xmark                \\
            ClientAuth               & ID / PW               & ID / PW            & ID / PW                & EC                    \\
            ServerAuth               & NONE                  & EC                 & EC                     & EC                    \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
```

But The PDF outputted is here.
[image]

Please help ME!
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

You should change definitions for `\cmark` and `\xmark`. Instead of use `color{...}` you should use `\textcolor{<desired color}{<symvol>}`. See MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\cmark}{{\Large\bfseries\textcolor{green!50!black}{\ding{51}}}} % <---
\newcommand{\xmark}{{\Large\bfseries\textcolor{red!50!black}{\ding{55}}}}   % <---

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{4pt}  % <---
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lCCCC}
                                     & {\scriptsize EAP-MD5} & {\scriptsize PEAP} & {\scriptsize EAP-TTLS} & {\scriptsize EAP-TLS} \\
            \hline
            ServerEC\footnotemark[1] & \xmark                & \cmark             & \cmark                 & \cmark                \\
            \hline
            ClientEC\footnotemark[1] & \xmark                & \xmark             & \xmark                 & \xmark                \\
            ClientAuth               & ID / PW               & ID / PW            & ID / PW                & EC                    \\
            ServerAuth               & NONE                  & EC                 & EC                     & EC                    \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
A we bit simpler code you can get by use of the `talltblt` of `tabularray` package. Using it and `booktabs` rules (which can be used at `tabularx` table too) obtained table is to my opinion nicer and more correct:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\newcommand{\cmark}{{\Large\bfseries\textcolor{green!50!black}{\ding{51}}}} % <---
\newcommand{\xmark}{{\Large\bfseries\textcolor{red!50!black}{\ding{55}}}}   % <---

\begin{document}

\begin{talltblr}[
caption = {table caption},
  label = {tab:?},
note{a} = {explanation ...},
note{b} = {explanation ...},
                ]{colspec = {l *{3}{X[c]}},
                  row{1} = {font=\footnotesize}
                  }
                        &   EAP-MD5 &   PEAP    &   EAP-TTLS    &   EAP-TLS     \\
    \midrule
ServerEC\TblrNote{a}    & \xmark    & \cmark    & \cmark        & \cmark        \\
    \midrule
ClientEC\TblrNote{b}    & \xmark    & \xmark    & \xmark        & \xmark        \\
ClientAuth              & ID / PW   & ID / PW   & ID / PW       & EC            \\
ServerAuth              & NONE      & EC        & EC            & EC            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! I can solve using `textcolor`.

Comment: @KokiMIZOGUCHI, you are welcome! BTW, see addendum to answer. It may better fit to your needs :-).